# Getting distinct records from a mysql query

Tags: mysql, join, distinct

In my application, there are publishers and categories.  One publisher can belong to several categories.  When I make my mysql transaction, it will return the same publisher record for each category it belongs to.  Here's the query:

```
SELECT
    grdirect_publisher.name,
    grdirect_publisher.short_description,
    grdirect_publisher.thumb_image,
    grdirect_publisher.url,
    grdirect_category.name AS catname
FROM
    grdirect_publisher
JOIN
    grdirect_publisher_categories
    ON
    grdirect_publisher.id = grdirect_publisher_categories.publisher_id
JOIN
    grdirect_category
    ON
    grdirect_publisher_categories.category_id = grdirect_category.id
```

returns:

```
name    short_description   thumb_image url catname
------------------------------------------------------------
Foo Lorem Ipsum...      images/pic.png  d.com   Video Games
Foo Lorem Ipsum...      images/pic.png  d.com   Music
Bar Blah Blah...        images/tic.png  e.com   Music
```

Essentially, Foo should only show up once in the results.

Comment: If you want Foo only to appear once, which catname would you like to see: video games, or music?

Comment: it wouldn't matter.  the group_concat gives me all of them in one column.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `DISTINCT` but if *any* column in your result set has a distinct value, it forces the row to be duplicated.  If you want to reduce the list to one row per `name`, then you have to use `DISTINCT` and you have to omit the `catname` column:

```
SELECT DISTINCT
    grdirect_publisher.name,
    grdirect_publisher.short_description,
    grdirect_publisher.thumb_image,
    grdirect_publisher.url
FROM
. . .
```

Another solution instead of using `DISTINCT` is MySQL's aggregate function `GROUP_CONCAT()` which allows you to take multiple values in a group and produce a comma-separated list:

```
SELECT
    grdirect_publisher.name,
    grdirect_publisher.short_description,
    grdirect_publisher.thumb_image,
    grdirect_publisher.url,
    GROUP_CONCAT(grdirect_category.name) AS catname
. . .
GROUP BY grdirect_publisher.id;
```

So you have to decide how you want the result set to look to get the right solution.